# Запретить создание объектов вне класса

Tags: php

структура директории:
libs - каталог
index.php - точка входа
В каталоге libs лежит файл test.php, содержимое которого:

```
class Test
{
    public function init()
    {
        echo 'init<br>';
    }
}
```

Содержимое файла index.php:

```
class Main
{
    public $prop;

    public function __construct()
    {
        include_once('libs/test.php');
        $this->prop = new Test();
    }
}
```

Проблема:

```
$m = new Main();
// Все обращения к объекту класса Test должны быть через свойство prop
// класса Main
$m->prop->init();

// Объект класса Test НЕ ДОЛЖЕН быть создан
$t = new Test();
$t->init();
```

Можно ли реализовать в php так, чтобы объект класса Test невозможно было создать вне конструктора класса Main?

Comment: Ну как минимум можно же использовать принципы инкапсуляции

Comment: Искусственное какое-то ограничение.

Comment: Мне кажется, или Вы пытаетесь переизобрести Singleton? Почитайте про этот паттерн, возможно это решит Вашу проблему.

Comment: @Oleg Создание синглтона проблему не решит. Вызов Test::getInstance() вне класса Main успешно создаст и вернет объект Test

Comment: @ДенисНестерюк Мне показалось что Вы хотите гарантировать работу с одним и тем-же объектом через `$m->prop`. Синглтон как раз гарантирует тот самый один и тот же объект. P.S. То, что Вы хотите, насколько я знаю, невозможно сделать средствами чистого PHP. Вы либо разрешаете всем создавать экземпляры класса извне, либо запрещаете всем.

Comment: @ДенисНестерюк В качестве костыля: Можно унаследовать `Main` от `Test`, а все методы пометить `protected`. Но все равно нет гарантии, что кто-то где-то в другом месте точно так-же не унаследуется, и обойдет Ваше ограничение.

Comment: @Oleg Тоже склоняюсь, что это невозможно. Вырезка из описания функции include:"Все переменные, доступные на этой строке во включающем файле, будут также доступны во включаемом файле.  Однако все функции и классы, объявленные во включаемом файле, имеют глобальную область видимости". Т.е. класс Test прямиком идет в глобальную обл. видимости.

Comment: @ДенисНестерюк Вот были бы в `PHP` `sealed` классы, тогда можно было бы что-то заколхозить с наследованием

Answer (score 1):

В пхп нет групп классов ( нет аналога с пакетов из java) , поэтому все другие классы кроме родителей и детей класса Test будут для него внешними, в том числе Main. Поэтому если из Main можно создавать Test и они не наследуют друг друга, что очевидно по названию, то его можно создавать откуда угодно, так как в этом случае конструктор должен быть публичным. 
Поэтому ответ нет, нельзя.
Тем не менее не ясна цель зачем так делать?  Паттерн нужны не столько для ограничения программистов сколько для передачи им идей как оно все тут работает, поэтому если не следовать известному паттерну то конструкция будет непонятна следующему разработчику и он тут же её сломает. Если синглтон не ложится на твою цель (должно быть несколько классов Test в каждом Main свой) почитай про dependancy injection, там присутствует третий класс который решает какой именно Test положить в очередной Main.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть так:

```
class test {
    function __construct() {
        $trace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS);
        if (!isset($trace[1]['class']) || $trace[1]['class'] != 'factory') {
            throw new Exception('Cannot create class test outside factory');
        }
    }
}

class factory
{
    function create() {
        new test();
    }
}

$factory  = new factory();
$factory->create();
echo "With factory\n";
new test();
echo "Without factory\n";
```

Результат:

```
With factory
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Cannot create  class test outside factory
```

Или вот так:

```
class test {
    protected function __construct($arg) {
        echo "{$arg}\n";
    }
}

class factory
{
    function create() {
        $reflection = new ReflectionClass('test');
        $constructor = $reflection->getConstructor();
        $constructor->setAccessible(true);
        $test = $reflection->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
        $constructor->invokeArgs($test, ['TEST']);
    }
}

$factory  = new factory();
$factory->create();
echo "With factory\n";
new test();
echo "Without factory\n";
```

Результат:

```
TEST
With factory
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to protected test::__construct() from invalid context
```